# Paypal subscription button

Tags: php, html, button, paypal

**Background**
I'm building a website where I need to use some sort of recurring billing payment method. My client does not have Paypal's Website Payments Pro so he decided to use a simple `Subscribe` button.

**Problem**
This is all nice and easy to use but *how would I get a notification from Paypal when such a payment has been made*? I had some experience with Paypal before and there was a field `return_url` that would be accessed by Paypal to notify the website but checking the variables on their site this field does not exist anymore or perhaps not available with this type of button.

Comment: `return_url` is the address where the user is sent after the payment is completed, `notify_url` is the IPN handler

Comment: Thanks for clarification but will that work with the Subscribe button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you create subscribe button that time you will find that option(in step 3) , so according your need you can set url and get ipn variable

Step 3: Customize advanced features (optional)

1. Take customers to this URL when they cancel their checkout

   ```
       http://yourwebsite/complete_registration.php?action=cancel&sts=0
   ```
2. Take customers to this URL when they finish checkout

   ```
       http://yourwebsite/complete_registration.php
   ```
3. Advanced variables

   ```
      notify_url=http://yourwebsite/complete_registration.php
   ```

i hope it help you

Comment: Thanks. My client created the button in his account so I was unaware of this.

Comment: By the way, if someone stumbles upon this question in the future, you can append these parameters in the form URL and would work the same https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr/?`notify_url=...&return=...&cancel_return=...`