# Paypal subscription button, dynamin amount

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have to use paypal subscription button. it is working fine. my problem is , If we can make amount dynamic. If not than what is the best option to configure subscription plan with dynamic amount.
My current button code is

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
      <input name="custom" type="hidden" id="custom" value="<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3); ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
     <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="valuedummy">
     <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once try this code

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/x-click-but20.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
</form>
```

or click this [link](https://www.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_subscr_techview_outside)
or [Paypal subscription button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870190/paypal-subscription-button)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a Paypal subscription page where the user can select from a number of subscriptions (radio buttons).  Each radio button has attributes with the values I need:

```
<input id="4" class="packageRadio" type="radio" value="4" data-desc="6 month package" data-type="M" data-period="6" data-amount="240.00" data-count="2" name="package">
```

When a user selects a package a jQuery click event function on the radio button adds the required values to my Paypal form.

Comment: BTW, your form looks incorrect for recurring subscriptions, look at the form posted by Naveen

Comment: i generate this code from paypal. and please tell me  how paypal recognize that this request is send from my side. is we use  
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
for this.

Comment: Paypal has a number of button generators - you need to use the one for subscriptions.  Yes, the 'business' input is correct.